# I received an error message when importing the import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Tags: matplotlib

When I import the import matplotlib.pyplot as plt below is the error message I received. please help me to resolve.

I reinstall the matplotlib but it didn't help

```
TypeError: deprecated() missing 6 required keyword-only arguments: 'message', 'name', 'alternative', 'pending', 'obj_type', and 'addendum'
```

Comment: It looks like your matplotlib install is broken or corrupted. The only safe way is to completely reinstall matplotlib. If that doesn't work, it means something went wrong during reinstall, which we can't know what it is from the information provided.

Comment: Thank you RalfFriedl, installed this ((conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib) package and got resolved.

Comment: below is another error message when creating the word cloud. installed pillow and import "from PIL import Image" still receiving the same error message.                                                                                        ImportError: The _imagingft C module is not installed

Comment: In that case not only matplotlib is corrupted, but pillow as well. I would reinstall everything from scratch.